# Links + params!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, token

I have database called "Auth", there are fields: id, auth, is_active, created_at, updated_at

i need following url => `'localhost:3000/?auth=lala9999'` (this I have in my database and this field should come from DB).

Auth = token. Yes. I need users allow enter on my site using tokens. Where  i can do check that definitely this token is from DB?

How can i do it?

**********EDITED******************

Comment: your question is about learning Rails from the beginning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i've understood correctly and you indeed talk about token based authentication, i'd propose Devise :

http://www.hyperionreactor.net/blog/token-based-authentication-rails-3-and-rails-2